# ESLint not working in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

ESLint is not working for me in VS Code. I have the plugin installed in VS Code, and ESLint itself as a developer dependency in my package.json, which I have installed as well.

I modified the following option in the VS Code User Settings:

```
{
  "eslint.options": { "configFile": "C:/mypath" }
}
```

I have use the command `eslint --init` to add the basic `.eslintrc.json` to the main directory of my package.

Other people were able to get ESLint feedback from VS Code using the exact same package with the exact same ESLint config file.

I have received no feedback of any kind when directly breaking multiple rules that were all included in the recommended rule set that is by default inside of the `.eslintrc.json` file.

What am I missing?

Edit: I have tested using ESLint via command line, and everything worked as expected, with the errors found where they should have, however, these same errors never showed up in VS Code. The issue seems to be on VS Code's side and not ESLint.

Comment: Note that, If you have installed **ESLint** successfully, but got no feedback from ESLint as you expected, then there's a chance that you might have forgotten to **initialize ESLint**. To do that, run this command from the root of your project `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init`

Comment: I had already seen in the terminal `TypeError: Could not find the rule "canonical/filename-match-exported".`, but I'd ignored it.

But I now think VSC was aborting there and not bothering to run any more rules.

Once I removed `/* eslint-disable canonical/filename-match-exported */` from the files that had those comments, VSC started honoring my ESLint rules (even in tsx files).

Comment: Run vscode command `ESLint: Show Output Channel` helped me spotted the problem.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are a few reasons that ESLint may not be giving you feedback. ESLint is going to look for your configuration file first in your project and if it can't find a .eslintrc.json there it will look for a global configuration. Personally, I only install ESLint in each project and create a configuration based off of each project.

The second reason why you aren't getting feedback is that to get the feedback you have to define your linting rules in the .eslintrc.json. If there are no rules there, or you have no plugins installed then you have to define them.

Comment: If you have a local .eslintrc.json you do not need to define your configFile in your settings.

Comment: I have the local `.eslintrc.json` already placed in the main folder of my project, and my rules extends the recommended rules by ESLint, which are the ones I was testing. I have also added some rules of my own to further test, but with no success.

Comment: When using ESLint directly via command line, everything works properly, and it finds all errors. The issue here seems to be with VS Code, and not ESLint.

Comment: try enabling eslint in your settings "eslint.enable": true. Make sure you don't have any eslint installed globally. and try to remove the configFile path. That is how I have my vscode set up. I run into a lot of problems when I have eslint globally and locally installed.

Comment: I already have it set to true, and I just tried uninstalling it globally, to only have it locally and I have removed the path option with no success.

Comment: Open up your output at the bottom of the screen. Change it to eslint up near the top right of the output window. Now what does it say in that window?

Comment: I noticed that sometimes it takes a couple of minutes to activate the changes or even you need to restart vscode before something takes effect. For sure, you need to restart the program each time to see if new setting works or not

Comment: For me, the issue was that I had not installed ESLint extension in VSCode.

Comment: I needed to create an `eslintrc.js` in the ROOT of my project (*i.e. not subfolders).

Answer (score 142):

If ESLint is running in the terminal but not inside VSCode, it is probably
because the extension is unable to detect both the local and the global
`node_modules` folders.

To verify, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in VSCode to open
the `Output` panel after opening a JavaScript file with a known `eslint` issue.
If it shows `Failed to load the ESLint library for the document  {documentName}.js` -or- if the `Problems` tab shows an error or a warning that
refers to `eslint`, then VSCode is having a problem trying to detect the path.

If yes, then set it manually by configuring the `eslint.nodePath` in the VSCode
settings (`settings.json`). Give it the full path (for example, like
`"eslint.nodePath": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs"`) -- using environment variables
is currently not supported.
This option has been documented at the [ESLint extension page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint).

Comment: thank you, spent a few hours figuring out why eslint did now work globally with vscode

Comment: I had the same issue. This helped me to resolve it but I didn't need to change the settings.json file.
I went into the `Problems` tab and clicked on the light bulb beside the error and on the pop-up window selected allow.

Comment: Honestly I was having the same issue, so restarted + updated VSCode and it just works now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Found my problem `- Unknown options: requireConfigFile`

Comment: If you install ESLint locally (not globally), then there is no need to do this.

Answer (score 125):

In my case, since I was using TypeScript with React, the fix was simply to tell ESLint to also validate these files. This needs to go in your user settings:

```
"eslint.validate": [ "javascript", "javascriptreact", "html", "typescriptreact" ],
```

Comment: TypeScript with React here, worked for me too. Thanks

Comment: TypeScript with React on Windows and this worked for me as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "user settings"? Is this `.eslintrc.json` or something else?

Comment: This is your `settings.json` file. You can open this file via the command palette, on macOS it's `Cmd + Shift + P` to open it, then search for `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`

Answer (score 72):

configuring working directories solved it for me, since I had multiple projects with own `.eslintrc` files openend in the same window.

Put this in your `.vscode/settings.json`

```
"eslint.workingDirectories": [
    "./backend", 
    "./frontend"
],
```

thanks to this guy on github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/696#issuecomment-542592372

PS: useful command to list all subdirectories containing an `.eslintrc` except /node_modules:

`find . .eslintrc | grep .eslintrc | grep -v node_modules`

Comment: NOTE:  On Windows 10, .vscode/settings.json in the root of our project were not taking effect, but they WERE for our Ubuntu WSL environments.   On Windows 10, the default settings.json was under our %appdata% folder, and when we modified it to have the "editor.codeActionsOnSave ...." lines, it started working.  The easiest way to get to the right settings.json is to go to the ESLint plugin settings and scroll to the bottom to find a link to it.   So again, on Windows 10 only, it was ignoring the settings.json in our .vscode folder in the root of our project.

Answer (score 58):

### Case 1/2: First-time plugin installation? approval is necessary

Little "weird" user experience (Hard to notice) - anyway - Since V 2.1.10 -
You must change the "currently block" status bar  [image] on New/First installation.

##### ESLint plugin Version `2.1.10` changelog (08/10/2020)

> no modal dialog is shown when the ESLint extension tries to load an
> ESLint library for the first time and **an approval is necessary**.
> Instead the ESLint status bar item changes to ESLint status icon
> indicating that the execution is currently block.

Click on the `status-bar` (Right-Bottom corner):
[image]

Opens this popup:

[image]

Approve ==> `Allows Everywhere`

[image]

-or- by commands:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + p -- `ESLint: Manage Library Execution`

[image]

**Read more here under "Release Notes":**

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

---

### Case 2/2: The plugin already installed/approve

Open the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

Under  **output** `ESLint` dropdown, you find **useful** debugging data (Errors, warnings, info).

[image]

For example, missing `.eslintrc-.json` throw this error:
[image]

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, realpath`

Next, check if the plugin enabled:
[image]

##### By default there is no need to edit eslint.probe

Last, Since v 2.0.4 - `eslint.validate` in "normal cases" (react, vue, typescript, js, html, md) **not necessary anymore** (**old legacy setting**)**

**Many out-of-date stackoverflow answers (even her) indicate that `eslint.probe` file should be edited.

> `eslint.probe` = an array for language identifiers for which the
> ESLint extension should be activated and should try to validate the
> file. If validation fails for probed languages the extension says
> silent. **Defaults** to [`javascript`, `javascriptreact`, `typescript`,
> `typescriptreact`, `html`, `vue`, `markdown`].

Comment: I think this one needs to be pinned - that Allow action was so non-obvious.  This fixed it all for me.

Comment: You should [edit] your question so that it doesn't rely on images. Users with visual impairments, or users with images blocked, will not be able to make use of the information that's hidden in images. Pictures can sometimes add to an an answer, but should never be the sole source of any information.

Comment: my status-bar does not have a eslint option

Comment: Case 2 worked for me!

Answer (score 18):

In my case, I had not installed the ESLint extension in VSCode, which was causing issue. Did it and it started working again.

Comment: I had to run `npm install` and then `Ctrl + Shift + p` and type/select "ESLint: Restart ESLint Server"

Answer (score 12):

Restarting VSCode worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

I resolved the issue by restarting the ESLint Server. You can do this by opening up the `Ctrl` + `P` menu. Then you can enter `> ESLint: Restart ESLint Server`.

Comment: Kudos This worked for me on windows afte running `npx eslint --init`

Answer (score 10):

Since you are able to successfully lint via command line, the issue is most likely in the configuration of the ESLint **plugin**.

Assuming the extension is properly installed, check out **all ESLint related config properties** in both project (workspace) and user (global) defined settings.json.

There are a few things that could be misconfigured in your particular case; for me it was JavaScript disabled after working with TypeScript in another project and my *global* settings.json ended up looking following:

```
"eslint.validate": [
  { "language": "typescript", "autoFix": true }
 ]
```

From here it was a simple fix:

```
"eslint.validate": [
  { "language": "javascript", "autoFix": true },
  { "language": "typescript", "autoFix": true }
]
```

This is so common that someone wrote a straight forward blog post about [ESLint not working in VS Code](https://dev.to/pixari/eslint-not-working-in-vs-code-5g4d). I'd just add, check your global user settings.json before overriding the local workspace config.

Comment: For me, in addition to what you've specified, I had to add `"javascriptreact"` and `"typescriptreact"` since my project uses React.

Comment: Great point. `javascript` and `javascriptreact` are [default values](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint#user-content-settings-options) but I think you would need to have `*scriptreact` added back for JSX files.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a global installation of ESLint, any plugins used in your configuration must also be installed globally. Like wise for local install.
if u have installed locally and properly configured locally, yet eslint isn't working, try restarting your IDE.
This just happened to me with VScode.

Comment: Ugh! I don't know why this didn't occur to me sooner. VSCode would not recognize module aliases defined in my Webpack config file and was displaying Eslint errors but running Eslint from the command line did not. Restarting VScode fixed the problem!

Comment: My problem was that I install eslint per-project (not globally) and I was using Docker, so I forgot to run `npm i` on my local machine.

Comment: Restarting the VSCode works for me :)

Answer (score 6):

In my case **ESLint** was disabled in my workspace. I had to enable it in vscode extensions settings.

Answer (score 6):

In my case setting eslint validate to :
"eslint.validate": [ "javascript", "javascriptreact", "html", "typescriptreact" ],
did the job.

Comment: 2023 update: This is an old legacy setting and should in normal cases not be necessary anymore.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had to enable the ESLint "Always Show Status" setting in VSCode:

[image]

Then linting results started showing up immediately in VSCode.

Answer (score 4):

I'm giving the response assuming that you have already defined rules in you local project root with *.eslintrc* and *.eslintignore*.
After Installing VSCode Eslint Extension several configurations which need to do in settings.json for vscode

`eslint.enable: true`
`eslint.nodePath: <directory where your extensions available>`

Installing eslint local as a project dependency is the last ingredient for this to work. consider not to install eslint as global which could conflict with your local installed package.

Answer (score 4):

I use Use Prettier Formatter and ESLint VS Code extension together for code linting and formating.

[image]

[image]

now install some packages using given command, if more packages required they will show with installation command as an error in the terminal for you, please install them also.

```
npm i eslint prettier eslint@^5.16.0 eslint-config-prettier eslint-plugin-prettier eslint-config-airbnb eslint-plugin-node eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^2.5.0 --save-dev
```

now create a new file name **.prettierrc** in your project home directory, using this file you can configure settings of the prettier extension, my settings are below:

```
{
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

now as for the ESlint you can configure it according to your requirement, I am advising you to go Eslint website see the rules (https://eslint.org/docs/rules/)

Now create a file name **.eslintrc.json** in your project home directory, using that file you can configure eslint, my configurations are below:

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier", "plugin:node/recommended"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "spaced-comment": "off",
    "no-console": "warn",
    "consistent-return": "off",
    "func-names": "off",
    "object-shorthand": "off",
    "no-process-exit": "off",
    "no-param-reassign": "off",
    "no-return-await": "off",
    "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
    "class-methods-use-this": "off",
    "prefer-destructuring": ["error", { "object": true, "array": false }],
    "no-unused-vars": ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "req|res|next|val" }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding configuration to .prettierrc solved my issue. The problem was not with the eslintrc.json file.

Answer (score 4):

For me, i did accidentally disable ESLint when some prompt was shown by it.

Doing below steps fixed it for me

1. `Shift + Command + P` and select `ESLint: Disabled ESLint`
2. Close vscode
3. `Shift + Command + P` and select `ESLint: Show Output Channel`

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem on windows, however sometimes eslint worked (in vscode) sometimes not. Later I realized that it works fine after a while. It was related to this issue: [eslint server takes ~3-5 minutes until available](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/440)

Setting enviroment variable `NO_UPDATE_NOTIFIER=1` solved the problem

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with eslint saying it was '..not validating any files yet', but nothing was reported in the VS Code problems console. However after upgrading VS Code to the latest version (1.32.1) and restarting, eslint started working.

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing a project with eslint as an package.json dependency, make sure you run `npm install`. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

After installing the Eslint npm package and/or VS Code Extension by Dirk baeumer, Create .eslintrc.js configuration file as per your coding conventions.

Then, Enable all ESLint configurations in VSCode settings as follows:

- Pressing shortcut key Ctrl + or Command + based on your OS OR search "Settings"
- Type **@ext:dbaeumer.vscode-eslint** in your Search bar
- Tick mark the following checkboxes

  - Eslint: Debug
  - Eslint: Enable
  - Eslint: Format Enable
  - Eslint: Lint Task Enable

Happy Linting

Comment: It's working for us on multiple computers and environments (Windows, Ubuntu WSL 1, Ubuntu WSL 2), and none of those need to be checked.   We don't have a "Eslint: Enable" option.

Answer (score 2):

The .eslintrc.js file had a typo . More specifically I tried to add a rule in a wrong way . Once I removed the falsey rule everything was working fine immediately .

Answer (score 2):

Tried many of these with not luck. Then I saw the error message about incompatible VS Code version in Output > Eslint.

Updating VS Code fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it wasn't working because I had added only one folder of the monorepo to the project, even though I had the `package.json` and the extension configured. I worked only when I added the whole project (which contained the `package.json` file) to the VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

*Windows user here.*

Tried everything, nothing worked. Finally removing the folder with eslint in .vscode/extensions and reinstalling fixed!

> C:\Users<user>.vscode\extensions

Answer (score 1):

For me, the latest version of eslint does not work correctly with Visual Studio code in all my packages, so I had to install an earlier global version:

`npm i -g eslint@7.32.0`

J

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution (not best):
Add an empty eslint.options to setting.json; this has worked for me:

```
"eslint.options": {}
```

Answer (score 1):

pls pay attention to the vscode

1. click "Open ESlint Output" as below picture
   [image]
2. opend the ESlint Output, check the error message and fix follow reminding
   [image]

like me, I remove `{"allowConstantExport":true}`  of rule "react-refresh/only-export-components" in .eslintrc.cjs file, then fix the issue
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

run this command - `npm init @eslint/config`

after this, a question will pop up saying: How would you like to use ESLint?

select: To check syntax, find problems, and enforce code style

answer next few questions according to your react project and what kind of styling you like.

This will create a .eslintrc.js file in your root directory and errors should start popping up in your repo.

NOTE: This you need to do in every new repo you create. This is to initialise ESlint in your repo

Answer (score 0):

Go to your settings.json file, add the following and, fix the eslint.nodepath. Tailor it to your own preferences.

```
 // PERSONAL
  "editor.codeActionsOnSaveTimeout": 2000,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true
  },
  "editor.fontSize": 16,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "eslint.codeAction.showDocumentation": {
    "enable": true
  },
  "eslint.nodePath": "C:\\{path}",
  "eslint.workingDirectories": ["./backend", "./frontend"],
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the `.eslintrc.json` file inside the `.vscode` folder. Once I moved it out to the root folder, ESLint started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can open `problem` tab to check there is an ESLint permission request or not. If you see it, try to click the lightbulb and fix the issue, it works for me.

[problem tab in vscode terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxRXp.png)

wish you luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Yarn version 2, it might be the culprit. For me, once I ran `yarn set version classic` and `yarn install` everything started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. ESLint extension was enabled and .eslintrc file had some rules but VS Code did not show any autofix for my code.

The problem was in my folder structure, it was something like that

```
-workspace-folder
  -client
    -node_modules
    -src
    -.eslintrc.json
    -package.json
    -...other files
```

After changing folder structure to the like below example, with the delete package-lock.json and reinstallation of all deps, VS code began to show es lint errors.

```
-workspace-folder
   -node_modules
   -src
   -.eslintrc.json
   -package.json
   -...other files
```

Comment: If you have the same problem, doesn't give an answer for telling it. It's better to upvote the question and/or give a comment for put some additional data.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem of eslint not working. When adding these extensions in .eslintrc.json file, it works fine for me :

```
"extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates",
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I followed https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started#installation-and-usage to setup the es-lint. But after the installation it's wasn't working.

Fix: But just restarting the vs-code solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case ESLint was properly installed and enabled and working in another workspace with identical settings.

What helped was to disable the extension in the workspace where it was not working, reload VSCode and then enable the extension back. Then it immediately started working.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a problem with using nvm to install node.

In a terminal, run `npm root -g` to get the global node_modules install folder. It should look something like `/Users/{username}/.nvm/versions/node/v16.12.0/lib/node_modules` (for mac).

Then, in the settings for ESLint, edit the Node Path to point to this node_modules location.

Answer (score 0):

I had `.eslintignore` defined and it referred to a subfolder that I was checking.

When I ran command line, `eslint` let me know that `.eslintignore` was blocking the analysis of my file.  In vscode no such message.

So double check your `.eslintignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to remove `tsconfigRootDir: __dirname` from `parserOptions` in my eslint config.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I checked logs. I see the `standart` in the error message

Then I run `npm install eslint-config-standard --save-dev`

It fixed the problem