# ESLint works in one VSCode project but not another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint

I have the ESLint installed globally in VSCode.  In one of my React projects it is working.  Later, I created a React Native projects using Expo and it isn't running there.

I saw that I had the following settings in my packages.json file for my React project:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.1.1",
    "eslint": "8.31.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.1",
    "next": "13.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
```

I copied the

```
"eslint": "8.31.0",
"eslint-config-next": "13.1.1",
```

lines into my React Native project like so:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~47.0.12",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "eslint": "8.31.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.1"
  },
```

but it still doesn't work, even after closing and reopening my React Native project.

I came across [ESLint not working in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093510/eslint-not-working-in-vs-code)

I've tried running eslint in a terminal in VSCode, but I get the following error in both my React and React Native projects.

```
C:\Users\myuser\source\globomantics> eslint
eslint : The term 'eslint' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ eslint
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (eslint:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: `npx eslint ...`? Or add a `scripts` entrypoint.

Comment: Did you also install it in the second project? Just copy-pasting the values doesn't do this.